# Ionic 1 push notifications with phonegap-push-plugin and ionic cloud

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, push

I'm trying to make a notification in my iOS app using `ionic`, `ionic.io` and [`phonegap-push-plugin`](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push), and I'm really stuck here.

I followed all the steps in the documentation, I generated an apn_dev certification, I created a Security Profile and I enabled notification in the xcode project, here is my libraries :

```
<script src="lib/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic.cloud.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

here is my app.js :

```
.config(function($ionicCloudProvider) {
    $ionicCloudProvider.init({
        "core": {
          "app_id": "xxxx"
        },
        "push": {
          "sender_id": "12345",
          "pluginConfig": {
            "ios": {
              "badge": true,
              "sound": true
            },
            "android": {
              "iconColor": "#343434"
            }
          }
        }
      });
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPush) {
      $ionicPush.register().then(function(t) {
        return $ionicPush.saveToken(t);
      }).then(function(t) {
        console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
      });
      $scope.$on('cloud:push:notification', function(event, data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

The subscription works fine, I get the log saying :

```
Token saved: XXXXXXX
```

I even checked the cloud server : The device token exists in the result of a GET from : https://api.ionic.io/push/tokens

BUT when I try to send a notification to the device, I get nothing.. What am I missing?

Comment: When you run the application on device did it ask to enable the push notification permission on device?

Comment: yes, it does...

Comment: did you create .pem file for push notification in iOS ?

Comment: yes, I created it.

Comment: So, I suppose you have uploaded the .p12 certificate to ionic.io push profile that you have created. If you have done this, one more thing. Are you building this in development mode or production mode?